# Setting the custom url dynamically?

Tags: php, sulu

The Sulu cookbook says that you can configure the base domain for custom urls in the webspace, e.g.

```
<custom-urls>
<custom-url>example.com/*</custom-url>
</custom-urls>
```

So we have to configure them for all environments like dev, stage. etc.
Is there a way to configure them dynamically via host, e.g.

```
<custom-urls>
<custom-url>{host}/*</custom-url>
</custom-urls>
```

(which, in fact results in an error)?